# Best automation tools that cover application working on PDA with Windows CE

Tags: testing, automation, windows-ce

There is one application which has developed for PDA device working with Windows CE 
Can anyone advise me on test automation tools that cover application working on PDA with Windows CE and mobileapplication too ? I have TestQuest in mind

Comment: This question is [probably off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource). It might be relevant on softwarerecs, though.